# browser requesting for images after text

Tags: http, browser, mozilla

Does a browser request for images after it finishes with the basic text and background. If yes, does this request behave like a separate HTTP request like ones coming up by clicking a link etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does a browser request for images after it finishes with the basic text and background.

No. The requests for images are started immediately when the browser sees an `<img>` tag, the browser doesn't wait until the page finishes loading. You can easily see it with the [Firebug network monitoring](http://getfirebug.com/network) for example.

> does this request behave like a separate HTTP request

Yes, an image request is a usual HTTP request. However, most of the time an existing connection is reused for that (see [persistent HTTP connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection)).